# How to append values using drag and drop into input form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm stuck at appending droppable values into input field. I'm able to add only one value at a time and with every dropped item I'm erasing previous value with a new one and I'm wondering is it possible to append dropped value instead of erasing with a new value.

Here is a code that I'm using

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget").draggable({
   helper: 'clone',
   activeClass: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
  $(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".list-group-item",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "drag-hover"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var badge = ui.draggable.find(".badge").text();
      $(this).text(badge);

    }
  });
});
```

And here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/4v3cf6L7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted first to flag a duplicate, but considering the simplicity of your question, all that i found would probably have been slightly confusing as it needed to extract the relevant part from answers (in some cases not even accepted), that are not directly related to your specific use case.

First, you are using a text input, it means appending your result will end up to a concatenation. With this system, your final value will be a string containing the dropped letters. (to be kept in mind when parsing the result).

The basic way is to concatenate with the existing value and give it back to your input, like this:

```
$(this).val($(this).val() + badge);
```

However, depending on your case, you probably want to do actions on your result before giving it back to the input. We're still working on a string here, so, for example:

```
//if you want to verify that the dragged item (letter) exits only once:
if($(this).val().indexOf(badge) < 0){
    $(this).val($(this).val() + badge);
}
```

NOTE: As some might guess, my attitude is influenced by recents posts about welcoming and google-searching. If you feel i shouldn't have answered, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. To be fair I'm still in learning process as  I'm trying to switch career (from spatial planning to IT sector) and here and there I might ask stupid question but every start is  hard :) Thank you once again, I ll test code asap